# Sitecore 6.5 change user control dynamically

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a collection of some items. Using * symbol I set user control (ascx) in presentation details for all of them. Now I have a problem because on of this items has to be display in another control. Is there some trick that allow me to change used control dynamically, for example checking url segment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using `wildcard` item called `*` with some presentation details defined on it. And now you want to display different components for one you the urls?

If you want to have completely different presentation, you can add another item as a sibling of the `*` item and put new presentation detail there. This item will be matched before the wildcard item, if the url segment is equal to this item name.

If you want to change only one or few components, you can use personalization for this component and `where the item name compares to ...` rule.

Answer (score 1):

Marek's answer is preferable, but for completeness I will provide another potential option.

It depends on how you are handling the wildcards. I don't think it will work if you are using the wildcard item module from the Marketplace and it might not play well with some of your existing code, but here goes...

You could place the required presentation details on the target items themselves. Then when you resolve the wildcard, you would need to change the context item to be selected target item. When the page loads, it will use the presentation of the newly set context item.

One way to achieve this would be to create a custom item resolver

```sharp
class WildCardItemResolver : ItemResolver
{
    public override Process(HttpRequestArgsargs args)
    {
        base.Process(args);

        // if Context.Item is as wildcard
        // look up the target item

        Context.Item = targetItem 
    }
}
```